# ¿Como mostrar panel de Grafana en mi web?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

mi duda es sobre la visualización de los gráficos en tiempo real en un web externa (en mi caso sera un Laravel, pero para simplificar estoy haciendo un PHP puro para probarlo ahora mismo).

Mi duda es respecto a poder ver las gráficas (no snapshots) en mi web para usuarios registrados a través de usuario o token.

El Reverse proxy esta configurado correctamente en /grafana/ con nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myPage.com;
  root /var/www/grafana;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

location /grafana/ {

# Esto me autologearia siempre con el mismo, por lo que no me valdria
#                proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER kiosk1;


                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}


}
```

index.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        GrafanaEmbed = {
            grafanaUrl: 'https://myPage.com/grafana/',
            dashboard: 'dashboad-name',
            queryParams: {
                dashnav: 0,
                // this is a base64-encoded string of username:password
                // for example on a *NIX machine (and Mac OS X):
                // $ echo "kiosk1:supersecret" | base64
                // a2lvc2sxOnN1cGVyc2VjcmV0Cg==
                auth: 'a2lvc2sxOnN1cGVyc2VjcmV0Cg==',
                theme: 'light'
            }
        };

        (function() {
            var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 'text/javascript'; d.async = true;
            d.src = https://myPage.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

embebed.js

```
!function(){"use strict";function a(a){var b=0;if(a.offsetParent)for(;;){if(b+=a.offsetTop,!a.offsetParent)break;a=a.offsetParent}else a.y&&(b+=a.y);return b}function $
```

**EN RESUMEN:
¿Alguien me puede aconsejar para poder integrar los paneles en mi propia web con login/tokens?**